# Make One-Row Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, naming

I'm unable to construct a dataframe from 3 individual numbers. I want to do this in order for a function to return the dataframe, which I then append to other existing results.

Desired result is a dataframe with columns named "a", "b" and "C", each containing the value of a, b, and c.

Try one:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
dat=pd.DataFrame([a,b,c], columns=list('abc')) #fails with size error
```

Try two:

```
dat=pd.DataFrame()
dat['a']=pd.np.nan
dat['b']=pd.np.nan
dat['c']=pd.np.nan

dat['c']=c # no numbers are added to the column; still has 0 rows
```

What am I missing here?

Desired result is:

```
    a  | b  | c
   -------------
    1  | 2  | 3
```

Comment: bonus ask would be for columns to be named according to object name (not specified directly).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame([[a, b, c]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Note that your "bonus ask" isn't really possible, because an object may be associated with multiple variables (think about it).

You may, however, consider using a dictionary.

```
data = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])  # the `index` argument is important 

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Comment: Or maybe `dat=pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abc'),index=[0]).fillna(dict(zip(list('abc'),[a,b,c])))`

Comment: @Wen yup, that is another way!

Comment: @coldspeed can you explain in the answer why the 'index' argument is important

Comment: @rrs it is important so pandas knows how to load the data into the DataFrame. This is especially required when passing a single record (dict) instead of a list of records.

Answer (score 7):

Notice , you should follow what cold and jpp's construction for creating the one row dataframe, but here I am try to fix your code. change DataFrame call to

```
pd.Series([a,b,c], index=list('abc')).to_frame(0).T
Out[15]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

**Single append**

For a single append, there is no need to create a separate dataframe to append.

```
# ensure columns ordered appropriately.
df = df[['a', 'b', 'c']]

# define values
values = [1, 2, 3]

# add values to row at end of dataframe
df.loc[len(df.index)+1] = values
```

**Multiple appends**

Continually appending dataframes is extremely inefficient.

A much better idea is to append your results to a list, to form a list of a lists. Then create a dataframe from this list of lists, and append to the original. This is because appending to a list is considerably cheaper than appending to a dataframe.

Suppose you have some values in an iterable `iter_values` containing data you wish to append. Each item in the iterable is a list of 3 numbers.

```
lst = []

# loop through iterable, adding items to list
for values in iter_values:
    lst.append(values)

# create dataframe from list of lists
df_append = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=list('abc'))

# append to original dataframe, ignoring index
df = df.append(df_append, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Sure. Appending 2 dataframes to add one row is not a good idea. Hope that makes sense.